# Is it possible to add more than mt-5 to my top margin?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, margin

I would like to align some elements on my website, I've already used mt-5 in my HTML, but I need a little more margin. How can I do this?

Comment: You'd need to build off of what Bootstrap does and create your own classes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no higher value in Bootstrap but you could make your own classes. The documentation says ["You can add more sizes by adding entries to the $spacers Sass map variable."](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/), but if you don't want to recompile the SASS you can make you own class like this:

```
.mt-6 {
    margin-top: 4rem; // or the value you want
}
```

The Bootstrap classes already use `rem` for the margin classes so it is better to stay with the same unit. The existing classes use these values (it could help you decide what you want to use for your value):

- `.mt-5` is set to `3rem` so this is 1rem unit higher.
- `.mt-4` is `1.5rem` (so you might want to use `1.5rem` higher for your class)
- `.mt-3` is `1rem`
- `.mt-2` is `0.5rem`
- `.mt-1` is `0.25rem`

If you use it consistently on the top of all elements in the row, it will not affect the responsiveness. But if you use it left or right also, then it can affect responsiveness because it affects the width.

Comment: I would suggest that you go by `%` when you can. `rem` can behave unexpectedly, depending on what the *default* `em` value is set to. So unless you define your own default `em` value at root level (browser default is 16px), the user can have their own set, default `em`. That's important to note.

Comment: @Martin Good note but not a problem here, because Bootstrap already uses `rem`s for their values in their margin classes so it has already defined `rem`

Answer (score 3):

You can add your own style like this:

```
<div style="margin-top: 100px;"></div>
```

Comment: hi! thank you, but is it usable in a responsive website?

Comment: It adds margins just like bootstrap's ```mt-5``` which just uses classes to add them. I just noticed though, ```mt-5``` would be adding margin to the top of the element so you would want to use margin-top instead of margin. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Check out the first example from Bootstrap's website [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/#examples)

Answer (score 1):

**Use the `rem` units for responsive website**

By using class

```
.mt-6{margin-top:5rem;}
```

By using id

```
#mt-6{margin-top:5rem;}
```

by inline

```
#mt-6{margin-top:5rem;}
```

```css
.mt-6{margin-top:5rem;}
#mt-6{margin-top:5rem;}
```

```html
// add by class
<div class="mt-6">This text</div>

// add by id
<div id="mt-6">This text</div>

// add by inline style
<div style="margin-top:6rem;">This text</div>
```